# How can Laravel ignore everything except certain prefix?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes

I have my angular app running off of my laravel route /

I have everything else under /api.

I want to be able to enable html5 mode in angular and maintain SPA like routing, but when I do, laravel catches the route.

So how can I get laravel router to ignore everything except api and the initial route?

using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do the following:

```
// Catch any routes except 'api'
Route::any('{all}', 'InitController@index')->where('all','^((?!api).)*?');
```

Comment: @JasonSpick Hmm. How your angular routes works? I had similar task some time ago. So when users tap `site.com/any/path/here` in browser, they received base template. Then angular started handle any path and making requests to `api` routes for getting any data. Like `.when('/any2/path2/here2', {
                templateUrl : 'some/url',
                controller  : 'someController'
            })`
Full page reload doesn't required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a catch-all route to render index view on every request - then let Angular handle routing. Remember, you will also need to create 404 pages etc within Angular app.

```
// API routes here

// Catch-all route to point everything to index page
Route::get('{something}', function() {
    return view('index');
});
```

With regards to the API routes, you need to place these above your catch-all route so that they return an API response.

Angular Routing

Are you using Angular 1 or 2? What angular router are you using? e.g. with Angular1 using `$location` you add `false` as 2nd parameter to `path`:

```
$location.path('/some-path/', false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. it still says route NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: typo - replace the `*` with `{something}` as per updated answer

Comment: ok, so that worked. But now the behavior is the same as aleksejj suggestion. every link reloads angular